# my index.php not working with localhost... but works with online and errors at the end

Tags: php

[error result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dThdQ.png) so yeah i want my php files to work with my localhost but my index.php seemed having problems making it work in localhost

also... my index.php works with other hosting sites then gets prob with loading modals and submit stuff..something like that...

so yeah this index.php tho..
http://pastebin.com/epMtBitS

since it exceeds the character limit, had to pastebin then...
i dont get why my index.php loads at online hosting sites(halfly working) but not in localhost

Comment: check `short open tags` in your php settings, enable if they are not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because of using wrong opening tags. You are using `<?` opening tabs in your document, instead of using `<?php` tag. It's important, because not every web server accepts this short version of opening tag.

One reason that you can use tag without `php` text is `<?= ...`, which equals to `<? php echo ...`.